# Setting and Getting Global Variable in xCode iOS App

Tags: variables, global

How can I set a global class containing sharedInstance and also how can I get and change the variable within from each viewcontroller?

The following is my code:

DataClass.h:

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject {
    int *toyid;
}
+(DataClass *)sharedInstance;
@end
```

DataClass.m:

```
@implementation DataClass
+(DataClass *)sharedInstance {
    static DataClass *myData = nil;
    if(nil == myData) {
        myData = [[[self class] alloc]init];
        myData.toyid=0;
    }
    return myData;
}
@end
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. You should do more research before posting to StackOverflow.com. And choose better tags, such as `Objective-C`.

If you are asking to have one and only one instance of a class, doing so is a [software design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) called [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Try googling "Objective-C" and "Singleton" for examples and discussion. Such as this question on StackOverflow: [What should my Objective-C singleton look like? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like)